# Symfony2 route based on host. With parameters

Tags: symfony, routes

I have followed the instructions here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html

To make the route based on the host. However I want to use parameters instead of hard coding. The documentation says you can use service parameters, but I seem to be having trouble getting the parameters to work.

Here is the code from routing.yml:

```
rc_course_new:
    pattern: /course/new
    host: "{ domain }"
    defaults: { _controller: CoursesRCWizardBundle:Wizard:new }
    requirements:
        domain: "%rc_domain%"
```

And here is the code from services.yml:

```
parameters:
    rc_domain: my.domain.com
```

I get this error (looks like it is not picking up the parameter but seeing it as a hard code):

```
Oops! Google Chrome could not find { domain }
```

Comment: did you include your services.yml before routing.yml? Did you clear your cache?

Comment: It seems that the problem in your browser. "Oops! Google Chrome could not find { domain }" appears when the browser can't reach the server.

Comment: It could also be the spaces in the host variable, try `host: "{domain}"` with no spaces.

Comment: It can't reach the server because the url seems to be being regenerated (instead of checked): http://%7B%20domain%20%7D/course/21390/edit instead of http://my.domain.com/course/21390/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix this:

In the routing:

```
rc_course_new:
    pattern: /course/new
    host: "%rc_domain%"
    defaults: { _controller: CoursesRCWizardBundle:Wizard:new }
```

In the services (might work better in the parameters file) file:

```
parameters:
    rc_domain: my.domain.com
```